# Необходимо осуществить анимацию кнопки при нажатии

Tags: javascript, css, css-animation

Столкнулся с проблемой анимации кнопки.
Мне необходимо сделать чтобы при клике кнопка меняла цвет, при повторном нажатии меняла на дефолт. Что-бы было понятнее, это кнопка "добавить товар в корзину" и "добавить товар в избранное". Вот пример как я пытался это  осуществить:

```
if (json['success']) {
  let body = document.getElementsByClassName('heart1').onclick = function() {
    let color = ['#000', '#333'];
    if (body.style.color != color[0]) {
      body.style.color = color[0];
    } else {
      body.style.color = color[1];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Вчитайтесь в название getElement**S**ByClassName  .... А onclick применяется на один элемент

Comment: да, я понимаю, но по какому методу производить поиск элемента? допустим у меня на странице множество товаров и мне необходимо, что-бы при клике на корзину окрашивался только этот значок.

Answer (score 1):

Всё намного легче чем вы думаете.
Вот пример кода, надеюсь помог вам.

---

Быстро объясню, `btns` будет сохранять в себя все найденные элементы с классом `btn-add-cart`, с помощью фора мы добавляем события onclick для каждого элемента. При нажатия на кнопку с классом `btn-add-cart` у нас добавляется класс `active` для даного элемента если его нет, а если он есть то удаляет его.

```js
const btns = document.querySelectorAll(".btn-add-card");

for(var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++){
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    this.classList.toggle("active");
  })
}
```

```css
.btn{
  padding: 12px 16px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .5s;
}

.btn:hover{
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

.active{
  border-color: red;
  color: red;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-add-card">Добавить в корзину</button>

<button class="btn btn-add-card">Добавить в корзину</button>

<button class="btn btn-add-card">Добавить в корзину</button>
```

Вот что у меня получилось, не знаю почему но тут этот код не будет работать так что лучше запустить в своём редакторе.

```js
const btns = document.querySelectorAll(".btn-add-card");

for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");

    if (window.localStorage.getItem(this.id) === null) {
      window.localStorage.setItem(this.id, "active");
    } else {
      window.localStorage.removeItem(this.id);
    }
  })
}

var keys = Object.keys(localStorage);
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  document.getElementById(keys[i]).classList.toggle("active");
}
```

```css
.btn {
  padding: 12px 16px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .5s;
}

.btn:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

.active {
  border-color: red;
  color: red;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-add-card" id="btn-add-cart1">Добавить в корзину</button>

<button class="btn btn-add-card" id="btn-add-cart2">Добавить в корзину</button>

<button class="btn btn-add-card" id="btn-add-cart3">Добавить в корзину</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, сейчас попробую

Comment: Как сделать так, чтобы при обновлении страницы сохранялось выделение?

Comment: @ДмитрийСоколов это уже делается через localStorage, тут уже потяжелее

Comment: @ДмитрийСоколов  **"Как сделать так, чтобы при обновлении страницы сохранялось выделение?"** Этого не было изначально в вопросе. Менять вопрос, когда уже дан ответ-плохая практика. Отвечающий может попасть в нежелательную ситуацию, когда ответ будет не соответствовать измененному вопросу. Поэтому нужно принять этот ответ и задать новый вопрос в отдельном топике.

Comment: @ДмитрийСоколов прошу посмотреть, я обновил ответ, но заранее предупреждаю тут код не будет работать, не знаю почему

Comment: @ДмитрийСоколов Ещё один очень важный момент, это будет работать по-разному для разных браузерах, так как он использует localStorage браузера а не пк. Если вы делаете всё с помощью PHP и Базы Данных будет легче просто создать таблицу и там сохранять выбранные товары для каждого пользователя.

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` - Возвращает **HTMLCollection** дочерних элементов, а значит нужен цикл для обхода коллекции и установления им стиля. Или  извращаться через `getElementsByClassName('heart1')[0]`

```
let hearts = `getElementsByClassName('heart1')`;

for (let i = 0; i < hearts.length; i++) {
    hearts[i].onclick = function(){
        alert("Finaly!");
    }
};
```